# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) WebSocket code not working for iOS

Tags: ios, kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project where I'm using WebSockets to send and receive messages. I have implemented a class `WsChat` for the WebSocket client, which works as expected on Android but not on iOS.

Here's the code for `WsChat`:

```kotlin
import com.bokutotu.dateappmobile.model.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

expect fun wsClient(url: String, config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit = {}): HttpClient

class WsChat(
    private val host: String = "127.0.0.1",
    private val port: Int = 8080,
    private val chatId: Int,
    private val userId: Int,
    private val initRecieve: (String) -> Unit,
    private val onReceive: (String) -> Unit
) {
    private val client = wsClient(host)
    private var session: DefaultClientWebSocketSession? = null
    private val sessionPromise = CompletableDeferred<DefaultClientWebSocketSession?>()
    private var initialMessageReceived = false
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    init {
        scope.launch {
            initSession()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initSession() {
        client.webSocket(
            method = HttpMethod.Get,
            host = host,
            port = port,
            path = "/message/$chatId/$userId"
        ) {
            session = this
            sessionPromise.complete(this)
            initReceivePipeline()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initReceivePipeline() {
        val session = sessionPromise.await()
        session?.let {
            for (frame in it.incoming) {
                frameHandler(frame) { receivedText ->
                    if (!initialMessageReceived) {
                        initialMessageReceived = true
                        initRecieve(receivedText)
                    } else {
                        onReceive(receivedText)
                    }
                    println("here")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun frameHandler(frame: Frame, receiveFunc: (String) -> Unit) {
        when (frame) {
            is Frame.Text -> {
                val receivedText = frame.readText()
                receiveFunc(receivedText)
            }
            else -> println("Unexpected Frame format")
        }
    }

    fun send(newMessage: NewMessageJson) {
        val json = Json.encodeToString(newMessage)
        scope.launch {
            val session = sessionPromise.await()
            session?.send(Frame.Text(json))
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        scope.cancel()
        client.close()
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly on the Android platform but it doesn't work on iOS. When I run the iOS app, the error is below.

```
> Task :shared:compileKotlinIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED
e: WsChat.kt:26:52 Unresolved reference: IO
```

I suspect that it might be related to the different threading models in iOS, or some nuances in KMM or coroutine that I may not be aware of. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how I could resolve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is only available for JVM, [ref](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html), use Default instead

Answer (score 2):

Checking the docs of [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html), you can see that it's only available on the JVM platform, hence the unresolved reference on iOS targets. You should use other dispatchers on iOS. Btw, you shouldn't need to use special dispatchers when using Ktor, because I believe it uses its own thread pool internally and should be safe to use from any thread.

---

Aside from this, you're kinda lucky that this works on Android.

The way you capture the session is unorthodox. This overload of `client.webSocket(...) { }` closes the session when the block reaches the end, so the code only works because you happen to be listening to the `incoming` channel until it's closed, and that happens inside the block, effectively only allowing external closure of the session and never by reaching the end of the block. (Also, you don't really use the `private var session` property, only the promise FYI.)

Instead, you should probably use the [webSocketSession](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket/web-socket-session.html) function. This one returns the session that you can close when you don't need it anymore. This would make it more clear when exactly the session ends and why it's ok to use it in `send` functions.

See an example here: https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/main/krossbow-websocket-ktor/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/ktor/KtorWebSocketClient.kt